# unhandled exception Reading data from Any Excel

Tags: c#, excel

how can I go around this error

`An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll`

Additional information: The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object `Sheet1`.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly"

on this code

```
using System.Data.OleDb;
 String sConnectionString ="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=      Book1;" + "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";


        OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection(sConnectionString);
        objConn.Open();
        OleDbCommand objCmdSelect = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1]",objConn);
        OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        objAdapter1.SelectCommand = objCmdSelect;
        DataSet objDataset1 = new DataSet();
        objAdapter1.Fill(objDataset1);
        objConn.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [Sheet1$] instead of [Sheet1].